# Convert long file name to short file

Tags: perl, batch-file

I have perl script file that contains variable that has long file name like `"C:\Program Files\Some Folder\MyFile.txt"`.

The file mentioned in the path does not exist. How do i convert this into short file name `(8.3)` format?

Comment: Do you want to know the short name of a file that _does not exists_? It is the same than trying to know its size or creation date: there is no way to _guess it_!

Answer (score 3):

You can't. There is no guarantee for a short name. You can only ask an existing file what it's shortname actually is. Note the shortname may change if a shortfile of that name already exists for a different long name file.

```
call :myshortfunction c:\windows
echo %sn%
pause

:myshortfunction
set sn=%~s1
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/04/14/113052.aspx

> I'm sure everybody has seen the autogenerated short names for long file names. For the long name "Long name for file.txt", you might get "LONGNA~1.TXT" or possibly "LO18C9~1.TXT" if there are a lot of collisions.
>
> What you may not know is that sometimes there is no tilde at all!
>
> Each filesystem decides how it wants to implement short filenames. Windows 95 uses the "~n" method exclusively. Windows NT adds the hexadecimal hash overflow technique. But some filesystems (like Novell) just truncate the name. "Long name for file.txt" on a Novell server will come out to just "LONGNAME.TXT".